# After installing ubutuntu, computer will not boot unless a Super Grub Disk is used

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently isntalled an old computer with the latest ubuntu. After installation when booting, all it shows is a black screen with the blinking cursor the upper left.

I boot into super grub and select the SO it boots just fine.

But I can't get it to NOT require super grub to boot.

I have tried:

1. Reinstalling grub-pc
2. Running update-grub

I got nothing else. There is no UEFI. No dual boot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does grub run at all from the internal disk?  If so a video problem likely.  Please add the text output of df -l /dev/sda  to your original posting, so we can see the partitioning type (MSDOS/GPT) and partitions present.

Comment: No it didn't. I was going to try to reinstall grub completely. But when I did, aptitude installed lilo. To my surprise that worked. So problem was solved.